# more then one device has same globle ip still internet is working.... how?

Tags: networking

i have a static IP from my ISP(for eg-> **123.202.21.45**).

i have configured my router with that **Static IP**, and my laptop is connected with that router and its ip is **123.202.21.45**. works great!!

but now i connected my phone and iPad to same network and getting same IP (**123.202.21.45**) on all those devices and internet still works great!!

local-ip of all devices are different as assigned by DHCP of router.

now question is how the network packets  are get identified , because all HOST having same global IP(**123.202.21.45**) .

Comment: The IP adress of your device are not 123.202.21.45, they are translated by your modem to its IP when it's go on the net, then when the answer to your request come back, your router know how to redirect it to your computer. Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation for futher informations.

Comment: i just search "what is my ip" in google... and all the devices connected with that network are showng same IP(123.202.21.45).

Comment: 123.202.21.45 is address of your modem (or even your ISP device). Your devices have their own IPs (local IP). Local IP works only on local area network and are set by DHCP.

Comment: You have not explained how you know, from what perspective they have the same IP. If a remote device thinks they have same IP, but a local device sees that they have different IP, then there is a NAT between it and the internet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A TCP/IP connection is identified by a 4-tuple: Source address, Source port, Destination address, Destination port.

A NAT (Network Address Translation) makes use of this to allow a single public address to be used by multiple machines by keeping track of which of the external 4-tuple are associated with the internal 4-tuple.

In other words, when two machines in your internal network connects to the same external server, they're assigned different source port so that the NAT can direct IP packets to the correct machine in the internal network.

Comment: It might be worth adding that the router is acting as the NAT device.